# SQL task for selection

Tags: postgresql

Exercise: Calculate the average price of all cars broken down by month in 2022, taking into account the discount. Sort the results by month in ascending order. Round the average price to two decimal places.

source table: brandorigin

| id | auto | price | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Lada Vesta, grey | 11243.44 | 2019-12-15 |
| 2 | BMW F80, red | 63761.75 | 2019-01-29 |
| 3 | Hyundai Elantra | 42584.06 | 2021-08-29 |
| 4 | Lada Samara, pink | 9902.40 | 2017-02-08 |
| 5 | Audi S3, grey | 18307.80 | 2020-05-12 |
| 1000 | ... | ... | ... |

My SQL query:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) AS month, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date)  AS year, ROUND(AVG(price * (100 - discount) / 100), 2) AS price_avg
FROM brandorigin
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) = '2022'
GROUP BY date 
ORDER BY date ASC
```

table : brandorigin (with my sql-query)

| id | month | year | price_avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022 | 38395.35 |
| 2 | 1 | 2022 | 21578.42 |
| 3 | 1 | 2022 | 44720.55 |
| 4 | 2 | 2022 | 68387.55 |
| 5 | 3 | 2022 | 29668.59 |
| 91 | ... | ... | ... |

The months in my summary table are repeated, so I need to somehow get the sum of all cars for the first month, then the sum of all for the second month, and so on. Without repetition, there should be exactly 12 lines (months). How can this be implemented?

[summary table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itZ3B.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GROUP BY is not correct, nor the ORDER BY. Both take the complete date, not just month and year.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) AS month, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date)  AS year, ROUND(AVG(price * (100 - discount) / 100), 2) AS price_avg
FROM brandorigin
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) = '2022'
GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date),  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date)
ORDER BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date),  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date);
```

You could also use the column numbers 1 and 2:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) AS month, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date)  AS year, ROUND(AVG(price * (100 - discount) / 100), 2) AS price_avg
FROM brandorigin
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) = '2022'
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1,2;
```